# How can I have my viewcontroller be an observer of a C++ written subject

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

Let's say I have an observer pattern code in c++. Something very similar to the code here : [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Observer_pattern&oldid=342672104#C.2B.2B)

How can I have a ViewController or an objective-C class be an observer of a subject written in c++?

Any code example is appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: [Objective-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B)

Comment: I understand Objective-C++. But my viewcontroller.h cannot inherit from the IObserver defined in c++ header or can it?

Comment: No, it cannot. You have to create a proxy object (in Objective-C) or a proxy class (in C++), and call the appropriate functions manually.

Comment: thanks for the pointers, if you can provide an example I'd gladly mark it answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Objective-C++, nor C++ can inherit from each other, you have to create proxy classes to interact with each other.

Tiny example, if you want to call a C++ method from Objective-C++.

```
class Foo : public IObserver {
    virtual void bar(int i) { printf("i is %d\n", i); } override;
};

@interface Baz : NSObject {
@public
     void* foo;
}
@end

@implementation Baz
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        foo = new Foo();
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    delete foo;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)barHappened:(int)i {
    foo->bar(i);
}
@end
```